# upgrade to 18.04, xmodmap settings reverting periodically and video performance

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I have a custom xmodmap config that is called on startup by running `xmodmap ~/.xmodmap` however it seems every hour or so these settings seem to be reverted to default. I then have to run that command manually.

Any ideas on what might be causing this? I'd prefer not to set up cron if I don't have to.

Also, (as an aside) I have to say video rendering seems to suck on the new Ubuntu. dropping so many frames (1080ti with 390 drivers), a lot of the video rendering seems to be CPU. If anyone has any recommends for that I'd be appreciative.

Comment: please separate unrelated topics into different questions

Comment: I know, the main problem is the keymap, the second is just an aside.

Comment: I also have this issue with the `xmodmap` reverts.  Also, calling my script seems to take several seconds each time during which the X seems to be frozen.  This prevents me from just calling it every twenty minutes.